# Is there a way to quit selenium driver without ending the session? (python)

Tags: python, selenium, session, selenium-webdriver, python-requests

I am using a PhantomJs webdriver to login to a webpage and (for memory purposes) I copy the session cookies into a requests.Session object that I subsequently use.

Now, I want to completely get rid of the selenium.webdriver object since it consumes too much memory and it is effectively useless from that point on.

However, after I call `driver.quit()` the connection to the server seems to be closed and my requests object is not logged in anymore.

Pseudocode:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import requests

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get(login_page)  # Do all the stuff here to login

client = requests.Session()
client.cookies.update({ck['name']: ck['value'] for ck in driver.get_cookies()})  # copy cookies

client.get(page_that_I_am_logged_in)  # works fine

driver.quit()  # quit the driver

client.get(page_that_I_am_logged_in)  # doesn't work anymore
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, it seems that the problem was not with the selenium driver closing the connection, but with the Session object not keeping it open.

Adding the following header solves the problem

```
client.headers.update({'Connection':'Keep-Alive'})
```